# Filebeat harvest rotated files

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, elk

Problem description:

I have relatively big **/var/log/messages** file which is rotated.
The file list looks like this:

```
ls -l /var/log/messages*
-rw-------. 1 root 928873050 Mar  5 10:37 /var/log/messages
-rw-------. 1 root 889843643 Mar  5 07:49 /var/log/messages.1
-rw-------. 1 root 890148183 Mar  5 07:50 /var/log/messages.2
-rw-------. 1 root 587333632 Mar  5 07:51 /var/log/messages.3
```

My filebeat configuration snippet:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - input_type: log
    paths:
      - /var/log/messages
      - /var/lib/ntp/drift
      - /var/log/syslog
      - /var/log/secure
    tail_files: True
```

With multiple **/var/log/messages*** files as shown above each time filebeat is restarted it starts to harvest and ingest the old log files.
When I have just one **/var/log/messages** file, this issue is not observed.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, Filebeat keeps track of files not by filename but with inode number which doesn't change when renamed. This is from Filebeat [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/how-filebeat-works.html).

> The harvester is responsible for opening and closing the file, which
>   means that the file descriptor remains open while the harvester is
>   running. If a file is removed or renamed while it’s being harvested,
>   Filebeat continues to read the file. This has the side effect that the
>   space on your disk is reserved until the harvester closes. By default,
>   Filebeat keeps the file open until close_inactive is reached.

Which means this is what happens in your case

1. Reads current *messages* file (inode#1) and keeps track of its inode number in the registry.
2. Filebeat Stops, but *messages* file rotated to *messages.1* (inode#1) and new *messages* (inode#2) file got created.
3. When Filebeat restarts then it will start reading

   - *messages.1* (inode#1) file from where it left off
   - *messages* (inode#2) since it matches the path you configured (/var/log/messages)

If your plan is to harvest all *messages* file even the rotated ones, then it would be better to configure the path as

> `/var/log/messages*`

Comment: Even if I copy the log file manually (i.e. cp /var/log/messages /var/log/messages.1) it seems to read both after restart.. At least I see twice amount of ingest rate in Kafka.

Comment: This is strange. It should not read from messages.1 file. Can you make sure that it in fact reading the contents from messages.1 file? You can do the following test, configure filebeat to output to file, following this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/file-output.html). Then manually create a messages file with few lines of content in it. Stop filebeat and copy the file to messages.1, then add new different lines in both files. Restart filebeat.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the syslog and security plugins were ON in the configuration. That triggered the loading of the rotated syslog files.